# Read Multiple text files and Finding longest word from each text files

Tags: java, text-files, java.util.scanner

i have a friends assignement of last year which had an interesting question and which i found good for praticing with text files manipulation in java. the question goes like this.

XYZ Company is a digital publishing company and want your help to develop a small
Java Application. The Java Application should :
1. Count number of java files that end with .txt in a directory/folder.
2. Display the longest word in each file.

Example of the outputs are shown below (assuming that filename are f1.txt , f2.txt and f3.txt):

```
Number of Files = 3
Longest Word in f1.txt = strachouming
Longest Word in f2.txt = newstraaach
Longest Word in f3.txt = revolutions
```

i have so far managed to do this but am stuck i cannot find a solution to this problem am fairly new to java and still learning the concepts.

```
package longestWordTxt;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Longestword {

         public static void main(String [ ] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
             File f = new File("C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/java");
                int count = 0;
                for (File file : f.listFiles()) {
                    if (file.isFile() && (file.getName().endsWith(".txt"))) { 
                          count++; 
                        } 
                }
                System.out.println("Number of files: " + count);


           //calling function longestWord
        new Longestword().getLongestWords();
     }


         //funtion longestWord
    public String getLongestWords() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String longestWord = "";
        String current;
        String [] word = new String[4];
        int i;

        for(i=1;i<5;i++) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/java/f"+i+".txt"));




        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            current = scan.next();
            if ((current.length() > longestWord.length()) && (!current.matches(".*\\d.*"))) {
                longestWord = current;
                }
            }
        System.out.println("Longest word in f"+i+".txt = " + longestWord);

        }

        longestWord.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").split("\\s+");

                return longestWord;
            }

    }
```

This is my result:

```
Number of files: 4
Longest word in f1.txt = disastrous
Longest word in f2.txt = disastrous
Longest word in f3.txt = heartbreaking
Longest word in f4.txt = heartbreaking
```

My problem is it the first two top words come from the f1.txt file and 2 bottom ones come from the f3.txt file. how can i fix that?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It really helps us if you take the small amount of time required to clean up your code before posting. Removing repetitive blank lines, fixing indentation, and using meaningful variable names all helps convey your intent and aids in our understanding.

Comment: am sorry. will take what you say in consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program you created calculates the longest word so far from all the files it has read. Meaning that 'disastrous' is the longest word in files f1 and f2.

If you want to get the longest word of each file separately and not in comparison with other files you should add this line of code at the end of each iteration of the for loop in your `getLongestWords()` method.

```
 longestWord = "";
```

Also the method `getLongestWords()` can be a `void` method since you do not need to use the string it returns.

Comment: thanks it works. i forgot that it kept the word in the string and not clearing it so its comparing the first file world to the f2.txt word thanks alot.